# Navigation Bar for Website

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I need help.

I have been at this for a good couple of hours. I am new to html and css. I have been googling the hell out of this question and the only thing that seems to work is the follow: http://codepen.io/wolfcry911/pen/HyLdg.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

- create a navigation with 4 links (Home, About Me, Contact, Resume) with a logo in the middle that can adjust to any screen size (tablets, laptops, smartphones). I have tried an unordered list with the logo as the 3rd item (didn't really like this way. Seemed very sloppy and couldn't get the logo to be in the center of the screen since the text lengths were different) and I have tried using the logo as a background image but I cannot seem to center the logo in the middle of the page or when I do, the text never adjusts around the logo, always through the logo. With the link above, I was able to understand about 50% of the css and when I tried to tweak it, I couldn't get the text aligned in the center of the navigation and I can not get the logo to fit into the navigation. Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 0;
}
#header {
  height: 56px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px #ebebeb;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}
#header ul {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
#header ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 97px;
}
#header ul li:nth-of-type(4) {
  margin-left: 217px;
}
#header ul li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 0 0 0;
  height: 28px;
}
#header ul li a:hover {
  background: rgb(235, 200, 35);
}
.logo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -48px 0 0 -108px;
  background: url(img/logo.jpg) 50% 0 no-repeat;
  background-size: 125px 56px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 56px;
  top: 20px;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .logo {
    bottom: 100%;
  }
  #header ul li:nth-of-type(4) {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  #header ul {
    width: 600px;
    position: relative;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Template</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="navigation.css">


</head>

<body>

  <div id="header">
    <a class="logo" href="index.html">
      <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="Michigan State" width="215" height="140" />
    </a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="index.html">About Me</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Contact</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Resume</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I am able to understand about 50% of the css code. So if someone could help explain what is going on with the ul, li, logo, and the @media format, that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: try this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNKPxK. Try to use responsive frameworks like Bootstarp. Your image link is not working.

Comment: where do you want the logo to be when the screen size is small?

Comment: I didn't think about that. I probably wouldn't want the logo to show up if it was displayed on 6 inch screen or lower.Thanks for the suggestion on bootstrap. I'll look into some tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic markup/layout for you. (BTW it's *very* basic). It's using positioning, and allows you to easily customize bits and pieces.

```css
.nav {
  margin-top: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 5px solid gold;
  border-top: 5px solid gold;
}
.link {
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
.link2 {
  left: 20%;
  background: green;
}
.logo {
  left: 40%;
  background: orange;
}
.link3 {
  left: 60%;
  background: purple;
}
.link4 {
  left: 80%;
  background: pink;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .link {
  position: absolute;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
.link2 {
  left: 25%;
  background: green;
}
.logo {
  display:none;
}
.link3 {
  left: 50%;
  background: purple;
}
.link4 {
  left: 75%;
  background: pink;
}
  }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="link link1">Link1</div>
  <div class="link link2">Link2</div>
  <div class="link logo">logo</div>
  <div class="link link3">Link3</div>
  <div class="link link4">Link4</div>
</div>
```

You can use media queries to add styling for different sized screens. For example, when my snippet gets smaller than a width of 800px, the 'logo' div will disappear, and yet when it gets wider, the logo div will reappear. (best viewed in full screen mode to see this effect)

It's just something simple, but i think you could work with this.

Answer (score 1):

`ul` is an unordered list which will show bullet points instead of numbers as with and ordered list, `ol`. They have the `list-style` set to none so the bullet points will not show and set the width of each element to a set width of 97px.

`ul li:nth-of-type(4)` is a CSS selector that was implemented in CSS3. It basically tells the browser for the 4th item of the unordered list, use these set styles. http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/

`ul li a:hover` is just what styles happen when the user hovers over the item of an unordered list.

`.logo` is a class. These styles handle the position, size, image used, and other styles to format the picture.

`@media`detects the size of the browser and depending on that size uses a different set of styles that are indicated. http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Check out that site, css-tricks.com. It has a lot of information which has helped me out a lot in the past, especially getting up to speed on all the new tricks and properties with CSS3.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you a brief explanation of what's going on but you should really read up on CSS. There are some great tutorials for beginners out there as well(codeacademy for example)

```
#header ul {
   margin: 0 auto; /* Centers the UL. */
   width: 800px; 
   padding: 0;
   list-style: none; /* Remove list bullets */
}
```

---

```
#header ul li {
   float: left; /*Floats the LI's meaning it will place them next to eachother instead of stacking them underneath eachother*/
   width: 97px;
}
```

---

```
  #header ul li:nth-of-type(4) {
    margin-left: 217px; /* Adds a left-margin to your fourth LI-itme(Resume). This is here so to prevent the link from overlapping the image. The left-margin should be the same width as you image. This needs to be added because your logo has position:absolute. */
  }
```

---

```
.logo {
position: absolute; /* This means that the image is taken out of the flow and can be placed anywhere on the page. 
Position absolute elements are relative to parent elements containing the position:relative style. In your case that's #header*/

left: 50%;/* places the left edge of the imaget 50% from the left*/
margin: -48px 0 0 -108px; /* adds a negative top/bottom margin to center the image. */
width: 125px;
height: 56px;
top: 20px; /* places the image 20px from the top.
}
```

The media queries is there to define what will happen to the menu when the window size is less than 800px

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. The tutorials that I have done never really went into the -50px, percentages, and the vast amount of formats available. Would you recommend W3 as a starter for CSS. I really enjoy codecademy but it never got into a huge variety of formatting in css. That is why I didn't understand the @media and the nth-of-type.

Comment: @user3115532: I would use [css tricks](http://css-tricks.com/) from time to time, as it's a great source for info.

Comment: @user3115532 I think the best thing you can do is first to learn the basics of CSS, be it through W3, codeacedemy or some other site. Once you got that down css tricks that jbutler483 recommended is a great source for info. I think you'll just have to learn all these tricks as you go and if you have the basics of CSS down it will be much easier. sorry if I'm not too much help here :)